# How to solved the Axios 503 error when call external api

Tags: aws-lambda, axios, http-status-code-503

I've deployed my lambda to AWS (NodeJS runtime).
I am using [axios](https://axios-http.com/) to do a post request with formdata to the URL:

```
https://autopaypm.com/rate.php
```

In my case:

1. Locally it works correctly
2. However, when running my code in the deployed Lambda it returns error 503

Error log of lambda shows the following:

```
2022-12-19T15:27:22.607Z    46cb1f4a-48b4-47c5-ab29-fb930e51a397    INFO    AxiosError: Request failed with status code 503
    at settle (/var/task/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:1855:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/var/task/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:2712:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1241:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE',
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http' ],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 5000,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: null },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: AxiosHeaders {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------059092898205449353940589',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,compress',
      'User-Agent': 'axios 1.2.1'
    },
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://autopaypm.com/rate.php',
    data: FormData {
      _overheadLength: 755,
      _valueLength: 35,
      _valuesToMeasure: [],
      writable: false,
      readable: true,
      dataSize: 0,
      maxDataSize: 2097152,
      pauseStreams: true,
      _released: true,
      _streams: [],
      _currentStream: null,
      _insideLoop: false,
      _pendingNext: false,
      _boundary: '--------------------------059092898205449353940589',
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3
    }
  },
  request: ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      socket: [Function],
      abort: [Function],
      aborted: [Function],
      connect: [Function],
      error: [Function],
      timeout: [Function],
      prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: true,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    _contentLength: null,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'autopaypm.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 10,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'autopaypm.com',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: false,
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular],
      timeout: 5000,
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 537,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 5000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [TimersList],
        _idleStart: 26956,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 545,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 540
      },
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
    },
    connection: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'autopaypm.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 10,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'autopaypm.com',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: false,
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular],
      timeout: 5000,
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 537,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 5000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [TimersList],
        _idleStart: 26956,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 545,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 540
      },
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
    },
    _header: 'POST /rate.php HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------059092898205449353940589\r\n' +
      'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,compress\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios 1.2.1\r\n' +
      'Host: autopaypm.com\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      'Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      options: [Object],
      requests: {},
      sockets: [Object],
      freeSockets: {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      scheduling: 'fifo',
      maxCachedSessions: 100,
      _sessionCache: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'POST',
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    path: '/rate.php',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: false,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      connection: [TLSSocket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      headers: [Object],
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      trailers: {},
      rawTrailers: [],
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 503,
      statusMessage: 'Service Temporarily Unavailable',
      client: [TLSSocket],
      _consuming: true,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular],
      responseUrl: 'https://autopaypm.com/rate.php',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'autopaypm.com',
    protocol: 'https:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 846,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function],
      _currentRequest: [Circular],
      _currentUrl: 'https://autopaypm.com/rate.php',
      _timeout: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'content-type': [Array],
      'accept-encoding': [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    }
  },
  response: {
    status: 503,
    statusText: 'Service Temporarily Unavailable',
    headers: AxiosHeaders {
      date: 'Mon, 19 Dec 2022 15:27:22 GMT',
      'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
      connection: 'close',
      'cross-origin-embedder-policy': 'require-corp',
      'cross-origin-opener-policy': 'same-origin',
      'cross-origin-resource-policy': 'same-origin',
      'permissions-policy': 'accelerometer=(),autoplay=(),camera=(),clipboard-read=(),clipboard-write=(),fullscreen=(),geolocation=(),gyroscope=(),hid=(),interest-cohort=(),magnetometer=(),microphone=(),payment=(),publickey-credentials-get=(),screen-wake-lock=(),serial=(),sync-xhr=(),usb=()',
      'referrer-policy': 'same-origin',
      'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
      'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
      expires: 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT',
      'server-timing': 'cf-q-config;dur=6.0000020312145e-06',
      'report-to': '{"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\\/\\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\\/report\\/v3?s=GIp512epRW9w2zVQIe7I1QuC0oML60qhkbrRUAbf9G0x3HePioEXWk5gcnv7rXloQF4vCPSJSWRaQ9dCCvI59HOKYI9Lo%2BMkcgnpRhkp1rgAk3aeQAdh4dyR7gBokKBD"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}',
      nel: '{"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}',
      vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
      server: 'cloudflare',
      'cf-ray': '77c129763b883095-SEA',
      'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400'
    },
    config: {
      transitional: [Object],
      adapter: [Array],
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 5000,
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      env: [Object],
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      headers: [AxiosHeaders],
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://autopaypm.com/rate.php',
      data: [FormData]
    },
    request: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: true,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: null,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      connection: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'POST /rate.php HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------059092898205449353940589\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,compress\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios 1.2.1\r\n' +
        'Host: autopaypm.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        'Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'POST',
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/rate.php',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'autopaypm.com',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    data: '<!DOCTYPE html>\n' +
      '<html lang="en-US">\n' +
      '<head>\n' +
      '    <title>Just a moment...</title>\n' +
      '    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n' +
      '    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">\n' +
      '    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">\n' +
      '    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">\n' +
      '    <link href="/cdn-cgi/styles/challenges.css" rel="stylesheet">\n' +
      '    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="35">\n' +
      '\n' +
      '</head>\n' +
      '<body class="no-js">\n' +
      '    <div class="main-wrapper" role="main">\n' +
      '    <div class="main-content">\n' +
      '        <h1 class="zone-name-title h1">\n' +
      '            <img class="heading-favicon" src="/favicon.ico"\n' +
      '                 onerror="this.onerror=null;this.parentNode.removeChild(this)">\n' +
      '            autopaypm.com\n' +
      '        </h1>\n' +
      '        <h2 class="h2" id="challenge-running">\n' +
      '            Checking if the site connection is secure\n' +
      '        </h2>\n' +
      '        <noscript>\n' +
      '            <div id="challenge-error-title">\n' +
      '                <div class="h2">\n' +
      '                    <span class="icon-wrapper">\n' +
      '                        <div class="heading-icon warning-icon"></div>\n' +
      '                    </span>\n' +
      '                    <span id="challenge-error-text">\n' +
      '                        Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue\n' +
      '                    </span>\n' +
      '                </div>\n' +
      '            </div>\n' +
      '        </noscript>\n' +
      `        <div id="trk_jschal_js" style="display:none;background-image:url('/cdn-cgi/images/trace/jsch/nojs/transparent.gif?ray=77c129763b883095')"></div>\n` +
      '        <div id="challenge-body-text" class="core-msg spacer">\n' +
      '            autopaypm.com needs to review the security of your connection before proceeding.\n' +
      '        </div>\n' +
      '        <form id="challenge-form" action="/rate.php?__cf_chl_f_tk=t6fpv0vGtE4mAJk9GQLU8TbtWiwHSQFEuG6Gdzm8S1E-1671463642-0-gaNycGzNCf0" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">\n' +
      '            <input type="hidden" name="md" value="rtPyyR93tNOMbqayhVxMKQziEDt8BhzPwKTTe2N6PF4-1671463642-0-AQ9mVpD3FlIMSiyOtauRl7MdIVC1-g6Ol1kP4vVFxGsL43dBjFrBdaKeHrNnqYvajrweVvweo7oKEVpp6LSjUdGSboW84LVcdZfBx0BYOKk__yeRK5447LRnJFR7PGw4A_uS0ckfhIrPPjtZfJOsP9sKnbpnA2K4YR9Wma9rLhgzR2_WBI3IPUzJ0eqVxWxLILMThnYRrOKCGBlN5kTlSlFik445OOpBhqKGyounxeFsWSywmPQl417KkAKuuR3pWeQOOCqbAL7I7xgSWd9ETar59mF0PXh3JquhwwN-YGoJsN6MbQkLo-6XdSuBq_fOdfZdW6yrUEEqQQavmPz5Ge3Ix1cpl5e1f1U4i5ALPp5IatpYlgUX0ZR4vNMLEm_pKExAnh3TCgHoJWzsOoGUrHlJleetQe2NZ3Bgy55XvAMCOQq6YYhCRk7Rj2QVl3fOxHi3scu2_cODUFE2wO2QfHnhZlygxbZH5oubErnrpaZfancl57Vtg1vFfyNi7lPJQENsDSmTGIIxkbd9dbc0xJ9LV-m34m1V85T_ASxymzHe">\n' +
      '            <input type="hidden" name="r" value="Y2B4YUjgtSCNRcY4iKN81fkH6kWzqbwqhunIoz9pSzQ-1671463642-0-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 +
      '        </form>\n' +
      '    </div>\n' +
      '</div>\n' +
      '<script>\n' +
      '    (function(){\n' +
      '        window._cf_chl_opt={\n' +
      "            cvId: '2',\n" +
      "            cType: 'non-interactive',\n" +
      "            cNounce: '33598',\n" +
      "            cRay: '77c129763b883095',\n" +
      "            cHash: 'a375c0faec69836',\n" +
      '            cUPMDTk: "\\/rate.php?__cf_chl_tk=t6fpv0vGtE4mAJk9GQLU8TbtWiwHSQFEuG6Gdzm8S1E-1671463642-0-gaNycGzNCf0",\n' +
      "            cFPWv: 'g',\n" +
      "            cTTimeMs: '1000',\n" +
      '            cTplV: 4,\n' +
      "            cTplB: 'cf',\n" +
      '            cRq: {\n' +
      "                ru: 'aHR0cHM6Ly9hdXRvcGF5cG0uY29tL3JhdGUucGhw',\n" +
      "                ra: 'YXhpb3MgMS4yLjE=',\n" +
      "                rm: 'UE9TVA==',\n" +
      "                d: '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',\n" +
      "                t: 'MTY3MTQ2MzY0Mi41OTcwMDA=',\n" +
      "                m: 'odOxRIL1vJNndPmIJ3mC/qADuj/FIpZ5NCkmVM6vyQk=',\n" +
      "                i1: '1zxbMpqvbQSRFC4Bq7+/9g==',\n" +
      "                i2: '4+4GXseEN7vcymDfx+xi7A==',\n" +
      "                zh: 'Oev3Y+sKRXNEgfkVBCrhnDx9ljgNO6nRwrhn83YSlQ4=',\n" +
      "                uh: '8lLCtslFfZvmCyk6pqTwM9JAv5r3oQHDtbfkp3KITII=',\n" +
      "                hh: 'C4FnNuX81zRujtHWn6Gz34qQOcUeMwE+vQ6kDfOOHVs=',\n" +
      '            }\n' +
      '        };\n' +
      "        var trkjs = document.createElement('img');\n" +
      "        trkjs.setAttribute('src', '/cdn-cgi/images/trace/jsch/js/transparent.gif?ray=77c129763b883095');\n" +
      "        trkjs.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');\n" +
      '        document.body.appendChild(trkjs);\n' +
      "        var cpo = document.createElement('script');\n" +
      "        cpo.src = '/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/orchestrate/jsch/v1?ray=77c129763b883095';\n" +
      "        window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash = location.hash === '' && location.href.indexOf('#') !== -1 ? '#' : location.hash;\n" +
      "        window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery = location.search === '' && location.href.slice(0, -window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash.length).indexOf('?') !== -1 ? '?' : location.search;\n" +
      '        if (window.history && window.history.replaceState) {\n' +
      '            var ogU = location.pathname + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash;\n' +
      '            history.replaceState(null, null, "\\/rate.php?__cf_chl_rt_tk=t6fpv0vGtE4mAJk9GQLU8TbtWiwHSQFEuG6Gdzm8S1E-1671463642-0-gaNycGzNCf0" + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash);\n' +
      '            cpo.onload = function() {\n' +
      '                history.replaceState(null, null, ogU);\n' +
      '            };\n' +
      '        }\n' +
      "        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);\n" +
      '    }());\n' +
      '</script>\n' +
      '\n' +
      '\n' +
      '    <div class="footer" role="contentinfo">\n' +
      '        <div class="footer-inner">\n' +
      '            <div class="clearfix diagnostic-wrapper">\n' +
      '                <div class="ray-id">Ray ID: <code>77c129763b883095</code></div>\n' +
      '            </div>\n' +
      '            <div class="text-center">Performance &amp; security by <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com?utm_source=challenge&utm_campaign=j" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></div>\n' +
      '        </div>\n' +
      '    </div>\n' +
      '</body>\n' +
      '</html>\n'
  }
}
```

`

Do we have any soltution for that? It come from the target site or from the lambda? Thank you so much